# How to store and retrieve NSArray as value and float as key in/from NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

A NSDictionary in my code contains NSArrays with their respective keys (keys are float variables). When I tried to retrieve the NSArray using their respective keys, I get null value. I tried using both ObjectForKey and valueForKey methods, however the result is null. 
'DictOfCoordinatesWrtDist' is a NSDictionary which contains 2-D coordinates(NSArray) as value and distance (NSNumber floatValue) as their respective keys. I want to retrieve those coordinates with their keys later in the code. While using objectForKey and valueForKey methods, the coordinates are null.

```
NSArray *AllDistsWrtBeacons = [DictOfCoordinatesWrtDist allKeys];
for( id dist in AllDistsWrtBeacons)
{ NSArray *beaconCoordinate = [DictOfCoordinatesWrtDist objectForKey:dist];


NSLog(@"X=%@ Y=%@", [beaconCoordinate objectAtIndex:0],[beaconCoordinate objectAtIndex:1]);}
```

P.S: The NSDictionary 'DictOfCoordinatesWrtDist' contains beacons coordinate (Value) with respect to their distance (key). After executing this code, I get null value as coordinate.

Comment: Please share some code, so we can see what's going on.

Comment: you have to parse float into string then use it as key.

Comment: Show me your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use direct float or integer, 
As `NSDictionarys` are only designed to deal with objects, a simple way to do this is to wrap the integer and float in a NSNumber object.

For example,

```
NSArray *arr1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"one",@"two", nil];
NSArray *arr2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"red",@"green", nil];

NSNumber *key1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.1];
NSNumber *key2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.1];

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:arr1,key1,arr2,key2, nil];

NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:key1]);

NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:key2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code.

```
NSArray *temp = @[@"1",@"2"];
NSDictionary *dic = @{
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] : temp,
                            @"Test1" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:22]
                            };
NSLog(@"Get dic with number = %@",[dic objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 [dict setObject:myArray forKey:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need convert your keys float to NSNumber or NSString like that:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
   @(YOUR float Value) : @[Your array]
};
```

And I think more readable declare it using literals

Comment: This should be comment!

Comment: Thanks, I changed my answer.